# Git config synced without permission between Macs

Tags: mac, git, sync

I have two Macs, one used by me and one by someone else, sharing the same Apple ID, but with different git configurations and OS versions. After using "Screen Share" for a quick code review, the code was pushed, but under the other Mac's git config. Checking global configurations revealed the git config changed to the ones on the other Mac. I can't understand how this happened. There were no command executions or file configurations and the pair session ended before the push was done. Is this an Apple auto sync thing? Any settings I can check to prevent such things?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by your "git config"?  You mean the file `~/.gitconfig` was copied from the other Mac to yours?  That's not a Mac screen sharing "feature" that I've ever heard of.  And if that's the location of the gitconfig file, your homedir is not synced thru iCloud, so using the same iCloud ID's (which is very dangerous, BTW) shouldn't have caused this.  Are you sure one person or the other didn't do a git-pull or something and pulled across commits including the gitconfig file?  Check the repo to make sure that file (or whatever config you mean) isn't checked in.

Comment: Hey. I am referring to `~/.gitconfig`, but it wasn't the whole file being modified, only name and email. Alias methods for example are different. Pulls, commits and pushes have been done so many times before, without this happening. I don't use iCloud and I think it wasn't ever running since I've just tried accessing it for the first time now and did not further agree to terms.

Comment: That's very strange, I can't explain it.  I just tried to recreate it using my 2 Macs, both logged into same iCloud ID).  Different gitconfig files, opened Screen Sharing between them (didn't do any git commands though), closed Screen Sharing, nothing changed in either gitconfig.  Sorry, not sure how it could have happened (I really don't think it's supposed to), maybe someone else will have a better idea.

Comment: I have no idea also. I presume Apple may be doing something hidden to users, just as they tracked via internet what apps were opening and slugged everybody's machines when their servers lagged.